# Running Git Clone Command in Docker Toolbox

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am running git clone command in my docker toolbox and it is working fine

```
git clone https://github.com/<user name>/docker-curriculum.git
```

But when i ran

```
cd docker-curriculum/flask-app
```

It is giving me below error

```
bash: cd: docker-curriculum/flask-app: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you tell me the steps to do it because I am new to docker

Comment: I am not able to reply in docker chat because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I joined in slack.